# Complex Square Root

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I am not sure where to begin on this:
Determine the images of all conic sections with a focus at the origin under the principal branch of the complex square root.
I probably have to use the formula u(x, y) + i v(x, y) = sqrt((x, y)) and view square roots via the polar form. 
Any and every suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polar form sounds like a good idea. Then you need to know what the conic sections look like in polar coordinates: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Polar_coordinates.

Comment: thank you for the link. :-)